# Unable to perform Junit Parameterized test execution

Tags: java, junit

**Issue** Getting the following error when running this small bit of code. I am attempting to learn Selenium and Junit automation, hence having teething problems. Please help.

> **Error** java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class jUnit.ParameterizedTest.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import java.util.*;

// Step 1
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest {

    // Step 2, declare global parameters.
    String username;
    String password;
    int zipcode;

    // Step 3, make a constructor of the class with same no. of parameters as the
    // the number of global parameters declared.

    public ParameterizedTest(String username, String password, int zipcode) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    // Step 4, get all paramter values to be tested in an Arrays.asList format.

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getData() {
        Object data[][] = new Object[3][3];

        data[0][0] = "U1";
        data[0][1] = "P1";
        data[0][2] = "Z1";

        data[1][0] = "U1";
        data[1][1] = "P1";
        data[1][2] = "Z1";

        data[2][0] = "U1";
        data[2][1] = "P1";
        data[2][2] = "Z1";

        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {
        System.out.println(username + "   " + password + "   " + zipcode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're importing the wrong `Parameters` class. Please use

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan, that did that trick. 
For next time, how would I know if I selected the wrong import??

Comment: If you're using JUnit you should not have any TestNG classes on your classpath. Please have a look where the TestNG.jar comes from and remove it. Afterwards you're no longer able to import TestNG classes.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I removed the testNG and everything is working okay now. Thank you again.